# If a nilpotent group has an element of prime order $p$, so does its centre.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, nilpotent-groups

This is **Exercise 5.2.1** of Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3ANilpotent%20group%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime%2C%20OR%20content%3Aorder%2C%20OR%20content%3Acentre&p=10), it is new to MSE. The closest I could find is the following:

[Prove that in a nilpotent group every normal subgroup of prime order is contained in the center.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/601417/104041)

### The Details:

*(This can be skipped.)*

Robinson's definition of the following is equivalent to the one given on [proof wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Normal_Series):

> Let $G$ be a group whose identity is $e$.
>
> A *normal series* for $G$ is a sequence of normal subgroups of $G$:
>
> $$\{e\}=G_0\lhd G_1\lhd\dots\lhd G_n=G,$$
>
> where $G_{i-1}\lhd G_i$ denotes that $G_{i-1}$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G_i$.

On page 122 of Robinson's book,

> **Definition:** A group $G$ is called *nilpotent* if it has a *central series*, that is, a normal series $1=G_0\le G_1\le \dots \le G_n=G$ such that $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is contained in the centre of $G/G_i$ for all $i$. The length of a shortest central series of $G$ is the *nilpotent class* of $G$.

### The Question:

> If a nilpotent group has an element of prime order $p$, so does it (*sic*) centre.

### Thoughts:

Let's denote by $g$ the element of $G$ of order $p$.

---

I'm not particularly well-versed in nilpotent groups.

---

Cauchy's Theorem for groups springs to mind:

> **Theorem (Cauchy):** For a finite group $G$, if a prime $p$ divides $\lvert G\rvert$, then $G$ has an element of order $p$.

I don't know whether it would help. I doubt it. There's nothing to say $G$ in the question is finite.

---

If $G$ is abelian, then $G=Z(G)$, so the question is trivial in this case.

---

Examples of infinite, nonabelian nilpotent groups can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115785/104041).

---

An example of a nonabelian, nilpotent finite group is the quaternion group $Q_8$. Its order is $8$, so Cauchy's Theorem suggests that $Q_8$ has an element of order two. It is not difficult to see that that element is $-1$. We have $Z(Q_8)=\{1,-1\}$. So the result holds here.

---

The last time I gave Robinson's book a good read was about three weeks ago. I need to get stuck in again if I stand a chance of doing the exercises.

I have an exam coming up in a few weeks, too, so I can't give each exercise as much time as I would normally.

---

Please help :)

Comment: I don't immediately know how to do a direct proof of what you want.  But it's well known that a finite group is nilpotent iff it's the direct product of its Sylow $p$-subgroups, in which case the result reduces to that of $p$-groups.  $p$-groups have nontrivial center by the class formula.

Comment: @D_S But this question is not about finite groups in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also not too hard to prove this statement directly by induction on the nilpotency class of $G$:

If the nilpotency class is 0 or 1, there is nothing to show, as $G$ is abelian in this case. So let the class of $G$ be greater than 1, and let $a \in G$ be any element of order $p$. If $a$ is in $Z(G)$, we are done. Otherwise, $a$ leads to an element of $G/Z(G)$ of order $p$, and by induction hypothesis we know that $G/Z(G)$ has an element of order $p$ in its centre. In other words, there is an element $b \in Z_2(G)$ such that $b \notin Z(G)$ and $b^p \in Z(G)$. Since $b$ is not in the centre of $G$, there is some $c \in G$ such that the commutator $[b,c] \in Z(G)$ is nontrivial. Now we can complete the proof by showing $[b,c]^p = [b^p,c] = 1$.

Comment: I think that usually $Z_0(G)=\{e\}$, $Z_1(G)=Z(G)$, and $Z_{k+1}(G)$ is the subgroup such that $Z_{k+1}(G)/Z_{k}(G) = Z(G/Z_{k}(G))$, so I think you mean $b\in Z_2(G)$ rather than $b\in Z_1(G)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for pointing it out! I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In the proof of **5.2.7** is proven that, for all primes $p$, $G$ has a $p$-subgroup containing all $p$-subgroups of $G$, say $K(p)$. Then $K(p)$ is clearly a characteristic subgroup of $G$, in particular, $K(p)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. If $G$ has an element of order $p$, $p$ a prime, then $K(p)\neq1$. But $G$ is nilpotent and so there exists $i\geqslant1$ such that $$[K(p),\underbrace{G,\ldots,G}_{i}]=1.\tag{1}$$ If $K(p)\leq Z(G)$ we get the result. On the other hand, if $K(p)\nleq Z(G)$, then let $i_0$ be the least positive integer such that $(1)$ holds. Thus $i_0>1$ and
$$H=[K(p),\underbrace{G,\ldots,G}_{i_0-1}]\neq1.$$
Finally, $H\leq Z(G)$ since $[H,G]=1$.

Comment: Thank you! Two questions: how is $K(p)$ characteristic in $G$ and how come $H\le Z(G)$?

Comment: If $g\in K(p)$ and $\varphi\in Aut(G)$, then $\varphi(g)$ has the same order of $g$, it means that $\varphi(g)$ is a $p$-element of $G$ and since $K(p)$ contains all $p$-subgroups of $G$ we get that $\langle\varphi(g)\rangle\leq K(p)$. Therefore, $K(p)$ is characteristic in $G$.

Comment: $H$ is a subgroup of the center of $G$ because every minimal normal subgroup of a nilpotent group is contained in its center. (Sorry for possible errors in English)

Comment: Are you sure that $K(p)$ (or even $G$) actually contains minimal normal subgroups of $G$? Otherwise you have to adjust your last argument slightly.

Comment: I was coming to university and thinking about that and I'm not sure that $K(p)$ necessarily contains a minimal subgroup, but I found another argument and it is correct.